# Best practice to store access token

Tags: ios, keychain

I have been using Keychain to store the access token. Does that make sense to have the API class fetch it from keychain every time it needs?
I used to fetch it once and store it in memory but people were saying it's not safe. What is the point here if you always retrieve it from keychain, it will come into memory eventually.
A determined hacker can get it if he wants.

Also, should the API class know about the access token (aka keep it as member var) ?